# Javascript [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint) to convert function

Tags: javascript, function, type-conversion, primitive

In JS functions belong to the object type. Objects can be converted to primitive types with `[Symbol.toPrimitive](hint)`. This pure-object conversion works fine:

```
let obj = {
  [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint) {
    switch(hint) {
      case "string": return "all right";
      case "number": return 100;
      default: return "something else";
    }
  }
};

alert(obj); // all right
alert(+obj); // 100
```

However, something is wrong with function conversion:

```
function fun() {
  [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint) { // JS engine starts to complain here
    switch(hint) {
      case "string": return "all right";
      case "number": return 100;
      default: return "something else";
    }
  }
}

alert(fun);
alert(+fun);
```

What am I missing here? How do I convert function to some primitive type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to address the function's `Symbol.toPrimitive` property and assign a function.

Otherwise you take an array with a symbol and try to call a function with it, which not exists.

```js
function fun() {
}

fun[Symbol.toPrimitive] = function (hint) {
    switch(hint) {
        case "string": return "all right";
        case "number": return 100;
        default: return "something else";
    }
};

console.log(fun);
console.log(+fun);
```

Answer (score 1):

The inside of the `{` block after `function(...){` has to be the function body only. To assign to a property of the function object, you have to do that *after* the function has been declared:

```js
function fun() {
}
fun[Symbol.toPrimitive] = function(hint){ // JS engine starts to complain here
  switch(hint) {
    case "string": return "all right";
    case "number": return 100;
    default: return "something else";
  }
};

console.log(fun);
console.log(+fun);
```

Answer (score 1):

`````
function fun() {
  this[Symbol.toPrimitive](hint) { // you need to to say the method is owned by the relevant object
    switch(hint) {
      case "string": return "all right";
      case "number": return 100;
      default: return "something else";
    }
  }
}
    ````

alert(fun);
alert(+fun)
`````

Comment: Do not post an answer with merely codes. While your solution can be useful, you should also explain why the code will fix the problem that was described in the question.